# echeck option NO Longer available in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to change my payment option to echeck on express checkout, on clicking change payment method link, the option for the echeck is not available.
What do i do? How do i create an echeck transaction.?

Even if you can give the NVP response from paypal it would be of great help.

Comment: There is currently a known issue with getting Internal server error when changing the funding source in the sandbox environment. 
 
But generally, to test eCheck as a funding option in the sandbox, remove the credit card from the buyer account and leave only the bank account.  This way there will be no back-up funding source for an instant transfer so eCheck will be displayed as a funding source choice on the checkout page.
 :)